# ruby scripts for chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

hey guys i am totally confused for writing ruby recipes for chef-solo.

```
package "python-setuptools"

execute "install_pip" do
    command "easy_install pip"
    user "root"
end

# install requirements

execute "install_requirements" do
    cwd "/home/vagrant/"
    user "root"
    command "pip install -r /home/vagrant/cheftutorial/src/requirements.txt"
end
```

when i put this code in default.rb it runs without error(i run it using chef-solo command), but it gives error when i run it using `ruby default.rb` why is that.

Comment: although you could write all this yourself for what you're doing here I suggest you take a look at some of the [readymade cookbooks](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks) from Opscode: eg https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/python (provides pip recipe and resource)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

About all of the commands you use in your recipe (here called resources) are provided by Chef itself. They are not part of the Ruby language. As such, your recipes can only run inside the Chef environment.

While you could probably prepare an environment similar to the one provided by Chef for the recipes by hand, you should look into [Shef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Shef) instead which provides an environment to develop and test recipes by hand.

Comment: hey, then where can i find more "resources" for writing recipes for chef-solo, as i am a beginner in chef-solo. thanks!

Comment: @itsme I am going through the same... it is the big flaw with the 'all magic' DSL approach taken by Chef. You are totally at the mercy of the documentation as it is impossible to tell by looking at the code where the code that makes it work comes from. Taken me about a week of pain to start to feel my way around.

Comment: @itsme The built-in resources are described [on a wiki page](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources) (you might want to put a copy of this page under your pillow at night). Cookbooks can add additional resources (or elements that act similarly, e.g. definitions). You might also want to browse that wiki a bit, esp. the [introduction to cookbooks](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Introduction+to+Cookbooks+and+More) and [the Anatomy of a Chef run](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Anatomy+of+a+Chef+Run).